# How to write a Snakemake rule with no output?

Tags: snakemake

My Snakefile has a `print_to_screen` rule **with no explicit output file**. The following is a simplified example:

```
rule all:
    placeholder_output  # What should I put here?

rule create_file:
    output:
        "file.txt"
    shell:
        "echo Hello World! > {output}"

rule print_to_screen:   # This rule has no output
    input:
        "file.txt"
    shell:
        "cat {input}"
```

**How can I write the `print_to_screen` rule so that it triggers other rules**, meaning that:

- it can be used as an input in other rules, so running `snakemake {placeholder_output}` also triggers the previous rule `create_file`?
- it can be included in `rule all`, so running `snakemake` triggers all rules?

Comment: I like to use log files, like this previous thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63467186/snakemake-how-to-create-rule-without-explicit-output-file-and-only-with-specif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `output` section of the rule is optional, but you need to make it the first rule (define it the first in your Snakefile) to take any effect:

```py
rule print_to_screen:
    input:
        "file.txt"
    shell:
        "cat {input}"

rule create_file:
    output:
        "file.txt"
    shell:
        "echo Hello World! > {output}"
```

If you need some flexibility (for example you have several rules like that) you should use *[flags](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#flag-files)*.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. For the general case with multiple rules I was considering using [log files](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#log-files) as output but the `touch` flag solution you suggest is more flexible and elegant.